# CSS 3 border-radius property; corners too pale in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use rounded corners with CSS 3, but I am getting a strange bug. In IE9, everything shows up fine. However, in Chrome, the corners themselves seem too pale when I try to add colours to the border. Anyone else getting this bug? Is it even a bug?

An example of what I am using is the following:

```
border: solid 1px #000000;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius:10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

[[SOLVED]]
Thanks for your help, but I found what the problem was.

I was rounding an image (probably should have specified this), and so the border rounding happened behind the image, i.e. the actual border was being rounded behind it, making it appear as though the border was thinner, or even transparent. By changing the image a little bit I managed to get the results I was looking for.

Thanks again everyone!
N.S.

Comment: Bear in mind that different browsers draw rounded borders differently. It's an implementation detail rather than an actual bug per se.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the border looks paler in Chrome. Can you post a screen shot? Maybe it's the anti-aliasing that makes it appear paler?

Comment: like @BoltClock says, browser will render it slightly differently. Using the old school approach of images might solve problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Could You create a screen shoot and test page somewhere?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below instead and remove the unnecessary [[SOLVED]] tags.

Comment: @BoldClock I will as soon as I can. StackOverflow is telling me to wait 3 hours since I don't have a high-enough score, so I posted this in the meanwhile to avoid having people answer unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rounded corners may also be affected by the browser's implementation of the CSS3 properties, `background-origin` and `background-clip`.

The **background-origin** property is used to determine how the background-position of a background in a certain box is calculated. The **background-clip** property is used to determine whether the backgrounds extends into the border or not.

The following screenshot [demonstrates the differences](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/) the two properties have on backgrounds and borders, which may be affecting your rounded corners.

[image]

The first row uses `background-clip: border-box`, while the second row specifies `background-clip: padding-box`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but I found what the problem was.

I was rounding an image (probably should have specified this), and so the border rounding happened behind the image, i.e. the actual border was being rounded behind it, making it appear as though the border was thinner, or even transparent. By changing the image a little bit I managed to get the results I was looking for.

Thanks again everyone! N.S.