# How to make Image Border Even?

Tags: html, image, css, xhtml

I added 1 pixel border to the image. At the same time I am trying to give radius to the image edges.
My problem is since the image is already rounded with photoshop, the border of edges look thinner than it should be

You can check it from here.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVNgA/

How can I make the border even?

```
img{ -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; }
<img src='http://carantina.com/wp/wp-content/themes/new/images/home_pic1.jpg'>​
```

Comment: i thing u want this http://jsfiddle.net/fVNgA/4/

Comment: @RohitAzad look to the edges. It is white or really thin. I want them to be even.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap image into a `span` and add `css` to it

http://jsfiddle.net/96wVp/

Answer (score 1):

Add "padding: 1px;" to the image styles :)

By the way, here is another thread outlining a similar issue, and the reasons for is: [CSS 3 border-radius property; corners too pale in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411701/css-3-border-radius-property-corners-too-pale-in-chrome-solved)

Comment: It will add padding, which is not sometimes what designer wants, see my answer below for precise picture

Comment: Yeah I agree, this is really just a hack I guess. My main point was that the other thread could explain and lead to an more exact match to the needs of the OP. For me the "1px padding" was good enough (not minding about the extra padding, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses square corners for the inner borders. So in Chrome, you won't be able to get the exact feel, where as in Firefox, it uses rounded corners even for the inner borders.

**Screenshot in Chrome and Firefox**

[image]

My advice is it is better to include the generic `border-radius` and also, for Chrome, a fix would be adding `overflow: hidden;` and `padding: 1px;`.

**CSS**

```
img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; /* Add this for fallback */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hack for Chrome */
    padding: 1px; /* Hack for Chrome */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**After Chrome Hack**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't so much the border as how it's applied and the image you're using. Try rounding the corners in Photoshop with a 6px radius and save it as a png with a transparent background. What's happening is you're placing a border then the border is actually moving under the corner of the image. Since your image is a jpg and jpg's don't support transparency your rounded corners actually have square white corners. Here is an example of your image with a transparent image rather than a jpg.
http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/fVNgA/6/

Code just because they won't let me post a fiddle without code... sometimes it makes sense >.>

```
<style>img{ -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; }    </style>
<img src='http://calderonline.com/images/home_pic1.png'>​
```